# Не подключаются стили css, настройка htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess

.htaccess имеет структуру:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test3/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Не подхватываются стили. Путь подключения css указан относительно корня. NetBeans всё правильно распознаёт. Может что дописать в htaccess нужно? [ВОТ ИСХОДНИКИ](https://yadi.sk/d/b8qgQtdo3EB25Z), распаковать как есть - `site.ru/test3/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Держи :)

Comment: Не работает всё равно

Comment: При этих правах заработало. Дописал в линке полный путь включая /test3/

Comment: > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d не работает